# Checking if my dictionary<int, list<int>> has an item in the list

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections

I am doing this right now:

```
foreach(..)
{
if(myDic.ContainsKey(car.ID) && myDic[car.ID].Contains(car.MfgID))
{

  // do something
}
}
```

I was wondering if I can perform the check, but check if it doesn't exist, and then just do a continue.

How would I do that? using a || or &&?

I cant' assume the key/value is there so I don't want it to crash.

Comment: What is the foreach looping through?

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach(..)
{
    if(!myDic.ContainsKey(car.ID) || !myDic[car.ID].Contains(car.MfgID))
    {
        continue;  
    }

    // do something
}
```

- If *car.ID* is not a key of *myDic*
  then first condition is true and
  there is no evaluation of 2nd
  condition.
- If *car.ID* is a key of *myDic* then
  the 2nd condition will be evaluated
  and it won't crash since the
  *myDic[car.ID]* has valid value.

If you have some logic in *"do something"* this way is useful since it uses the good access complexity of the dictionary. If *"do something"* is just selecting values so the whole loop is just a filter it's more elegant to use a LINQ query.

Answer (score 1):

If you have LINQ available you could do something like this:

```
myDic.Any(kvp => kvp.Key == car.ID && kvp.Value.Contains(car.MfgID));
```

Figured I would add a little expansion, if you want to filter the list you could do the following:

```
var filteredDictionary = myDic.Where(kvp => kvp.Key == car.ID 
                                         && kvp.Value.Contains(car.MfgID));

foreach(...)
{
    ... //Only enumerating over items that match both conditions.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another common way to do it is to use several simple [guard clauses](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html):

```
foreach (...)
{
    if (!myDic.ContainsKey(car.ID))
       continue;

    if (!myDic[car.ID].Contains(car.MfgID))
       continue;

    // do something actually
}
```

(it can improve readability sometimes)

Answer (score 0):

What you have is fine, the right side of an && is not evaluated if the left side evaluates to false.